# How to adjust the width of the ag-grid container based on its contents?

Tags: ag-grid

In ag-grid, the value of `domLayout` can be set to `autoHeight` in order to disable vertical scrolling of the ag-grid panel. Instead, the entire page adapts its height to show all the rows.

How can I have the same behavior for the horizontal scrolling?

There is the `suppressHorizontalScroll` option when set to `true` hides the horizontal scroll bar, but this doesn't force the entire page to have a scroll. Instead, the overflowing content is just hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this to some extent by juggling the `minWidth`, `maxWidth`, and `width` attributes on your columns while setting the width of the columns automatically based on their content using the `gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(colId)` method.

I say to some extent because it is quite hard, with agGrid, to set different row sizes for rows with certain cells having a lot of text or big images in them. This would force some columns to expand to accommodate for the content, or just clip it completely. Thus forcing the horizontal scroll.

Note : for the method above to work, you need to call `gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(colId)` after you get your rows setUp.